# Irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[X], \mathbb{Q}[X], \mathbb{R}[X]$ and $\mathbb{C}[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Is the polynomial $2X^3-10X^2+50X+10$ rrreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[X], \mathbb{Q}[X], \mathbb{R}[X]$ and $\mathbb{C}[X]$.

---

What I have done so far is, since this is a cubic function, therefore it will have roots in $\mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{C}$ , hence this polynomial is reducible in both $\mathbb{R}[X]$ and $\mathbb{C}[X]$. By Eisenstein's criterion with prime = 5, it is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$.

However $\{2,-10,50,10 \}$ are not co-prime in $\mathbb{Z}$, so I cannot use the lemma to say it is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$.

Lemma: If $f \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ is primitive in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ and irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, then it is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$.

Comment: Since the coefficients share a factor besides $\pm 1$, there is a factorization of the polynomial into two nonunits in ${\mathbf Z}[x]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the polynomial is $2(x^3 - 5x^2 + 25x + 5)$, and the polynomial in brackets is again irreducible over the integers by Eisenstein. We can divide by the gcd of all coefficients, i.e., by $2=gcd(2,-10,50,10)$. However, $2$ is not a unit over the integers. 
Hence the polynomial is reducible over the integers. 
Over the real numbers there must be a zero by the mean value theorem, hence the polynomial is reducible over the real and complex numbers.